# Places Autocomplete Status Code 9001

Tags: android, google-places-api

I was trying to get places prediction using the Places Autocomplete API from Google Play Services, but this is the status I got:

```
Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 9001, resolution=null}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the solution

- Enable "Places API **for Android**" in the API console

Note: Somehow, the switch to enable it can only be found in the old style console.

**Update**
You can find this option by typing "Places API for Android" in search bar.

Comment: Haha, I had enabled "Places API" instead of "Places API for Android". Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same problem. I also can see those logs:

03-26 08:58:48.564   26494-3999/? W/Places﹕ f.a:633: gLocReplyElement unsuccessful status: 1
03-26 08:58:48.564   26494-3999/? W/Places﹕ f.a:660: gPlaceQueryResult unsuccessful responseCode: 27

Maybe it will be useful. I just want to let you know that you're not alone and make you feel better.

**Updated:**

I just noticed that I receive this log message on all the devices I have:

03-26 10:22:33.774  26494-26721/? E/MDM﹕ [20882] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}

Maybe there is a problem with the Google Places API at the moment. This library seems to be raw yet. For example, there are only 3 constants for place types (PlaceTypes.ALL, PlaceTypes.zzanS and PlaceTypes.zzanR) and the last 2 don't make sense for me.