# Android places auto complete through error of 9001

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using example defined in [Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/03/hello-places-api-for-android-and-ios.html).

This is [git](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete) repository.

I am getting following error.

```
com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/PlaceAutocompleteAdapter﹕ Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 9001, resolution=null}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270524/places-autocomplete-status-code-9001

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

> Enable "Places API for Android" in the API console

Note: Somehow, the switch to enable it can only be found in the old style console.