# Google Places API Android resultCallback not firing

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I'm using the Google Places API for Android and I can't seem to get a `resultCallback` from a `PendingResult` to fire. Here's my code (essentially identical to the sample code to https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete except in a Dialog)

```
adapter = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getAdapter();
googleApiClient = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getGoogleApiClient();

final AutoCompleteTextView tvCity = new AutoCompleteTextView(getActivity());
tvCity.setAdapter(adapter);

tvCity.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = adapter.getItem(position);
        final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);

        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                .getPlaceById(googleApiClient, placeId);
        placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {

            if (places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    final Place place = places.get(0);
                    cityCoordinates = place.getLatLng();

                } else {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There was an error, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;

                }
                dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
                places.release();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you create a key for the API, added to the project and so on?

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban Yeah of course, the autocomplete part itself is working correctly. Just when I click on an item in the autocompletetextview the ResultCallback part never fires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue because I was missing the permission that allows the API to access Google web-based services

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Comment: Yep that was it, thanks! I'm surprised there's so little documentation about this issue...

Comment: You're welcome! What made it even more confusing for me was that GeoDataApi.getPlaceById calls in my app would work for a short period of time only after I ran the official sample on my device using the same API key. Google Play Services must cache API key authorization, which then allows that key to be used from another app that doesn't request the READ_GSERVICES permission.

Comment: Yeah I had that same experience!

Comment: @Alex Baker,  I'm still facing that problem although my app already uses the required permission. I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801555/getplacebyid-fails-to-return-data-on-android-google-places-api-resultcallbac
Can you guys help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, to anyone who visits this question, make sure you do all 3 steps below:

Add your API key to your app manifest

```
<application>
...
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
</application>
```

Then include in your manifest as @Alex Baker suggested

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

And also enable **Google Places API for Android**. Google Places API is a different API and your calls will fail with [Places AutoComplete status 9001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270524/places-autocomplete-status-code-9001)

Comment: You don't need the maps API_KEY in there for the Google Places for Android API

Comment: You're absolutely right Alex, I happened to have the maps API_KEY because I was using the Google Maps V2 API, and I thought it would work for the places API too... But, no, that was wrong. Even if it's the same key we have to put it in its own tag on android manifest.