# getPlaceById() fails to return data on Android google places API / resultCallback not getting called

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I cannot retrieve Place Details using the Google Places API on Android. I'm calling getPlacyById() for specific place_id.

Inside an Android activity I setup a googleApiClient and call connect(). The apiClient connects successfully.

Then for testing purposes I call getPlaceById() using a hardcoded place_id and a resultCallback. However, the resultCallback never gets called.

The hardcoded place_id is tested through javascript (using the javascript Google Maps API) and returns valid data. but the Java code below fails to return any data.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_activity_layout);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    if (getActionBar() != null) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        rebuildGoogleApiClient();
    }
    .....
    code_for_activity_init
    .....
}

protected synchronized void rebuildGoogleApiClient() {
    // When we build the GoogleApiClient we specify where connected and connection failed
    // callbacks should be returned, which Google APIs our app uses and which OAuth 2.0
    // scopes our app requests.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            //.enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    // Successfully connected to the API client. Pass it to the adapter to enable API access.
    //addressesAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
    Log.i("place api conn", "GoogleApiClient connected.");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    // Connection to the API client has been suspended. Disable API access in the client.
    //mAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
    Log.e("place api conn", "GoogleApiClient connection suspended.");
}

@OnLongClick(R.id.one_more_request)
public boolean getDataAgain(){
    Log.d("place", "getPlace By Id");
    PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
            .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, "ChIJIV6Mkke9oRQRcPq3KAx513M");
    placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
    return true;
}

private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
        = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            // Request did not complete successfully
            Log.e("place", "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());

            return;
        }
        // Get the Place object from the buffer.
        final Place place = places.get(0);

        // Format details of the place for display and show it in a TextView.
        //mPlaceDetailsText.
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,/*setText(*/
                        formatPlaceDetails(getResources(), place.getName(),
                place.getId(), place.getAddress(), place.getPhoneNumber(),
                place.getWebsiteUri()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.i("place", "Place details received: " + place.getName());
    }
};
```

this question is similar to [Google Places Api resultCallback not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744045/google-places-api-android-resultcallback-not-firing) however I have checked that my AndroidManifest already includes the the required permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Ultimately I would like the getPlaceById() to be called every time the user selects an item from an autocomplete Address field.

***** UPDATE *******
Solution found. I was missing two things. First, copy-paste the maps.v2.API_KEY this time as geo.API_KEY (and make sure you delete the maps.v2.API_KEY, because it cannot be specified twice)

<strike>android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"         android:value="whatEverGoogleMapsApiKeyYouHave"</strike>

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="whatEverGoogleMapsApiKeyYouHave"/>
```

and secondly I had to enable Google Places API for Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing two things.

First of all the com.google.android.geo.API_KEY which is the same as the com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY. Just copy paste the API KEY on the AndroidManifest file.

<strike>android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="whatEverGoogleMapsApiKeyYouHave"</strike>

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="whatEverGoogleMapsApiKeyYouHave"/>
```

I was also missing the **Google Places API for Android** Service on google console. If you have **Google Places API** enabled , beware, this in not enough, because it's simply a different API. You have to go to google console and explicitly enable the Google Places API for Android.

****** EDIT ******** 
As @Lissy pointed out, from SDK 21 onwards, defining the same API_KEY twice will give an error. Keeping the geo.API_KEY will suffice

Comment: Hi kouretinho; thanks for updating with the solution! I suggest you accept your own answers, so that everyone else can benefit from what you've worked out.

Comment: Hi @plexer, yes, I will accept the answer, I just need to wait one more day to do so!

Comment: @kouretinho this answer is not correct any more, it will return an error for SDK 21 and greater. See update

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE for SDK 21**

If you have both meta-data's included you will get the following error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The API key can only be specified once.
```

Instead just indlude the geo API key:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="whatEverGoogleMapsApiKeyYouHave"/>
```

and NOT the maps one

Answer (score 0):

This exactly what I've been struggling with.  In Android Studio when I added the 2nd API key I received an exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The API key can only be specified once.
```

This was resolved by just adding the "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" meta-data entry to the Manifest file and removing the maps one.